# Python script fails with a lot of data

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, confluence

I wrote a python script that seemed to work pretty well. It lists EC2 instances in AWS and then writes them to our Confluence wiki.

If it processes one environment with 10 servers it works and writes to Confluence. If it works against an account with 100 or more servers it fails to write to Confluence with this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 550, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 543, in main
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 391, in write_data_to_confluence
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\tdunphy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content/138317098
```

I've also raised a verbose error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 538, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 531, in main
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_orig.py", line 380, in write_data_to_confluence
    raise RuntimeError(r.content)
RuntimeError: b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected character \'<\' (code 60); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity \'C\'\\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,46579]","reason":"Bad Request"}'
```

Please note I AM NOT ALLOWED TO POST THE COMPANY DOMAIN IN MY POSTS. I will substitute 'company.com' where my real company domain would be.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Import modules
import boto3
import time
import objectpath
import csv
import os
import sys
import json
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
import codecs
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import basename
from subprocess import check_output,CalledProcessError,PIPE

BASE_URL = "https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/rest/api/content"
VIEW_URL = "https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId="

def banner(message, border='-'):
    line = border * len(message)
    print(line)
    print(message)
    print(line)

def initialize(interactive, aws_account):
    # Set the date
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    # Set source files
    aws_env_list="../../source_files/aws_environments/aws_environments_all.txt"
    output_dir = "../../output_files/aws_instance_list/csv/"
    output_file = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + aws_account + '-' + today +'.csv'
    output_file_name = 'aws-instance-master-list-' + aws_account + '-' + today +'.csv'
    return today, aws_env_list, output_file, output_file_name

def authenticate():
    #auth = get_login()
    auth = ('tdunphy', 'local4tl4nt1cNJ!')
    auth = str(auth).replace('(','').replace('\'','').replace(',',':').replace(')','').replace(' ','')
    kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication="DISABLED",principal=auth)
    auth = kerberos_auth
    return auth

## These are dummy AWS account numbers. I cannot post account number for my company.
def aws_accounts_to_account_numbers(aws_account):
    switcher = {
        'company-lab': '123456789101',
        'company-bill': '123456789102',
        'company-stage': '123456789103',
        'company-dlab': '123456789103',
    }
    return switcher.get(aws_account, "nothing")


def list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive):
    today, aws_env_list, output_file, output_file_name = initialize(interactive, aws_account)
    engagement = None
    # Set the account
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
    ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    fieldnames = [ 'AWS Account', 'Account Number', 'Name', 'Instance ID', 'VPC ID', 'Type', 'Platform', 'State', 'Key Name', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Private DNS', 'Volumes', 'Availability Zone', 'Launch Date', 'Engagement Code']
    # Set the ec2 dictionary
    ec2info = {}
    public_ips_list = ''
    private_ips_list = ''
    private_dns = None
    with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
    if 'gov' in aws_account and not 'admin' in aws_account:
        print("This is a gov account.")
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-gov-west-1')
    else:
        print("This is a commercial account.")
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account,region_name='us-east-1')

    ec2 = session.client("ec2")
    # Loop through the instances
    instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
            for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
                launch_time = instance["LaunchTime"]
                launch_time_friendly = launch_time.strftime("%B %d %Y")
                tree = objectpath.Tree(instance)
                block_devices = set(tree.execute('$..BlockDeviceMappings[\'Ebs\'][\'VolumeId\']'))
                if len(block_devices) == 0:
                    block_devices_list = None
                else:
                    block_devices_list = list(block_devices)
                    block_devices_list = str(block_devices_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','').replace('{','').replace('}', '')
                private_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))
                if len(private_ips) == 0:
                    private_ips_list = None
                else:
                    private_ips_list = list(private_ips)
                    private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                public_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PublicIp'))
                if len(public_ips) == 0:
                    public_ips_list = None
                else:
                    public_ips_list = list(public_ips)
                    public_ips_list = str(public_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\'','')
                if 'KeyName' in instance:
                    key_name = instance['KeyName']
                else:
                    key_name = None
                name = None
                if 'Tags' in instance:
                    try:
                        tags = instance['Tags']
                        name = None
                        for tag in tags:
                            if tag["Key"] == "Name":
                                name = tag["Value"]
                        for tag in tags:
                            if tag["Key"] == "Engagement":
                                engagement = tag["Value"]
                            else:
                                engagement = None
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Instance: %s has no tags" % instance_id)
                if 'VpcId' in instance:
                    vpc_id = instance['VpcId']
                else:
                    vpc_id = None
                if 'PrivateDnsName' in instance:
                    private_dns = instance['PrivateDnsName']
                else:
                    private_dns = None
                if 'Platform' in instance:
                    platform = instance['Platform']
                else:
                    platform = None
                ec2info[instance['InstanceId']] = {
                    'AWS Account': aws_account,
                    'Account Number': aws_account_number,
                    'Name': name,
                    'Instance ID': instance['InstanceId'],
                    'VPC ID': vpc_id,
                    'Type': instance['InstanceType'],
                    'Platform': platform,
                    'State': instance['State']['Name'],
                    'Key Name': key_name,
                    'Private IP': private_ips_list,
                    'Public IP': public_ips_list,
                    'Private DNS': private_dns,
                    'Volumes': block_devices_list,
                    'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'],
                    'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly,
                    'Engagement Code': engagement
                }
                with open(output_file,'a') as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
                    writer.writerow({'AWS Account': aws_account, "Account Number": aws_account_number, 'Name': name, 'Instance ID': instance["InstanceId"], 'VPC ID': vpc_id, 'Type': instance["InstanceType"], 'Platform': platform, 'State': instance["State"]["Name"], 'Key Name': key_name,  'Private IP': private_ips_list, 'Public IP': public_ips_list, 'Private DNS': private_dns, 'Volumes': block_devices, 'Availability Zone': instance['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], 'Launch Date': launch_time_friendly, 'Engagement Code': engagement})
    for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
        print(Fore.RESET + "-------------------------------------")
        for key in [
            'AWS Account',
            'Account Number',
            'Name',
            'Instance ID',
            'VPC ID',
            'Type',
            'Platform',
            'Key Name',
            'State',
            'Private IP',
            'Public IP',
            'Private DNS',
            'Volumes',
            'Availability Zone',
            'Launch Date',
            'Engagement Code'
        ]:
            print(Fore.GREEN + "{0}: {1}".format(key, instance.get(key)))   
        time.sleep(2)
    print(Fore.RESET + "-------------------------------------")
    with open(output_file,'a') as csv_file:
        csv_file.close()
    return output_file


def convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file, today, interactive, aws_account):
    output_dir = "../../output_files/aws_instance_list/html/"
    if interactive == 1:
        htmlfile = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + aws_account + '-' + today +'.html'
        htmlfile_name = 'aws-instance-master-list-' + aws_account + '-' + today +'.html'
    else:
        htmlfile = output_dir + 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.html'
        htmlfile_name = 'aws-instance-master-list-' + today +'.html'
    count = 0
    html = ''
    with open(output_file,'r') as CSVFILE:
        reader = csv.reader(CSVFILE)
        with open(output_file,'r') as CSVFILE:
            reader = csv.reader(CSVFILE)
            html += "<table><tbody>"
            for row in reader:
                html += "<tr>"
                # Process the headers
                if count == 0:
                    for column in row:
                        html += "<th>%s</th>" % column
                else:
                    # Process the data
                    for column in row:
                        html += "<td>%s</td>" % column
                html += "</tr>"
                count += 1
            html += "</tbody></table>"
    with open(htmlfile,'w+') as HTMLFILE:
        HTMLFILE.write(html)
    return htmlfile, htmlfile_name


def get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid):
    # Get basic page information plus the ancestors property
    url = '{base}/{pageid}?expand=ancestors'.format(
        base = BASE_URL,
        pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()['ancestors']


def get_page_info(auth, pageid):
    url = '{base}/{pageid}'.format(
        base = BASE_URL,
        pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.json()


def write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title = None):
    info = get_page_info(auth, pageid)
    ver = int(info['version']['number']) + 1
    ancestors = get_page_ancestors(auth, pageid)
    anc = ancestors[-1]
    del anc['_links']
    del anc['_expandable']
    del anc['extensions']
    if title is not None:
        info['title'] = title
    data = {
        'id' : str(pageid),
        'type' : 'page',
        'title' : info['title'],
        'version' : {'number' : ver},
        'ancestors' : [anc],
        'body'  : {
            'storage' :
            {
                'representation' : 'storage',
                'value' : str(html)
            }
        }
    }
    data = json.dumps(data)
    url = '{base}/{pageid}'.format(base = BASE_URL, pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.put(
        url,
        data = data,
        auth = auth,
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    print("Wrote '%s' version %d" % (info['title'], ver))
    print("URL: %s%d" % (VIEW_URL, pageid))

def main():
    pageid = 138317098
    title = 'AWS EC2 Instance List'
    aws_account = input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
    aws_account_number = aws_accounts_to_account_numbers(aws_account)
    today, aws_env_list, output_file, output_file_name = initialize(interactive, aws_account)
    output_file = list_instances(aws_account,aws_account_number, interactive)
    htmlfile, htmlfile_name = convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file, today, interactive, aws_account)
    with open(htmlfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as htmlfile:
        html = htmlfile.read()
    auth = authenticate()
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why does this script fail to write to confluence only when it processes a lot of servers?

Comment: I don't remember the fine detail about aws policy around ec2 & sdk, however, it is worth checking the maximum number of instance details that you can access through SDK. By default, it is restricted to protected your ec2 from accessing via script. Look at the developer guide. Also, worth looking at any alternative approach ( API methods) which allow you to access large number of instances.

Comment: You'll need to look at the actual error returned. Instead of `r.raise_for_status()`, try `if r.status_code >= 400: raise RuntimeError(r.content)` or similar, then tell us what it says.

Comment: @Nair That's not the problem here. You can see the error stems from writing data into Confluence, not the EC2 API.

Comment: Thanks when I enable the detailed error like you showed me I get this: `RuntimeError: b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Error parsing xhtml: Unexpected character \'<\' (code 60); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity \'C\'\\n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,32068]","reason":"Bad Request"}'` . If I run it against an account with only 5 instances I get success: `Wrote 'AWS EC2 Instance List' version 112
URL: https://wiki.us.cworld.company.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=138317098`

Comment: You do not properly htmlize the data from AWS and in the larger sample is something that invalidates the generated xhtml.

Comment: Ok. Do you think using a templating engine like Jinja2 might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky to diagnose without being able to see the data you're working with. As noted by fpbhb, the error message suggests that there is an issue with the generated html (probably an `&` somewhere in the input). I would try escaping the CSV field data before wrapping it in the HTML tags:

```py
from html import escape


def convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file, today, interactive, aws_account):
    # [...]

    count = 0
    html = ''
    with open(output_file,'r') as CSVFILE:
        reader = csv.reader(CSVFILE)
        html += "<table><tbody>"
        for row in reader:
            html += "<tr>"
            # Process the headers
            if count == 0:
                for column in row:
                    html += "<th>%s</th>" % escape(column)
            else:
                # Process the data
                for column in row:
                    html += "<td>%s</td>" % escape(column)
            html += "</tr>"
            count += 1
        html += "</tbody></table>"
    with open(htmlfile,'w+') as HTMLFILE:
        HTMLFILE.write(html)
    return htmlfile, htmlfile_name
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I'm getting an error when I escape the html `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 568, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 542, in main
    htmlfile, htmlfile_name, remove_htmlfile = convert_csv_to_html_table(output_file,today, interactive, aws_account)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 312, in convert_csv_to_html_table
    html += "<th>%s</th>" % column % html.escape(column)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'escape'`>

Comment: I can try showing you the data, but there's a lot and I need to scrub important company info first.

Comment: Whoops, that `html` package gets clobbered (overwritten) by your local `html` variable. Try again as edited.

Comment: OK, thanks! I'm trying your suggestion now. It takes a while to run. I'll let you know!

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But why did that solve the problem?

Comment: Great! The problem was that HTML has certain special sequences of characters called [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). They start with a `&` and end with a `;`. Somewhere in your CSV input data there was at least one `&` character and the HTML parser treated it as the beginning of an HTML entity, looking in vain for the corresponding `;`. `html.escape` solves this by replacing the special HTML characters `&`, `<` and `>` with their own HTML entities, so that the parser receives valid HTML.

Comment: Ah great! Thank you very much indeed. It's great to know the problem and understand the solution. I really appreciate you sharing that info! I look forward to making great use of that knowledge!

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for the bounty as well. Good luck!

Comment: Sure! Quite welcome on that! Glad I could award the bounty for such a helpful answer! Thanks again!